# Output data on the console from Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a following snippet code in a Controller:
`echo 'something';`

So, I need to show it on console listener that I created with:

```
tail -f storage/logs/laravel.log
```

I've tried so many things:

```
\Log::info('info');
\Log::warning('warning');
\Log::error('error');
\Log::debug('debug');

error_log('something log');
```

I have configured AppServiceProvider.php

```
    public function boot()
    {
        //
        error_reporting(E_ALL & E_NOTICE);
    }
```

In config/app.php, I have:
`'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),`

Nothing works!

What else do I need to do?

Comment: `echo 'Something'` will not output anything to the console, as Controller code is generally not run via the console... Running a command like `php artisan custom:command`, and using `$this->info('Something')` would output to the console. The `Log::` statements write data to `storgae/logs/laravel.log`, so they _should_ work via `tail -f ...`

Comment: Is your storage directory writeable?

Comment: Anything methods (info, warning...) from "Log" class does not work. I don't know what, but probably I'm doing something wrong. Need I configure something in Log class write in laravel.log? I suspect it's not happening...

Comment: Aditional information, artisan commands erros are recorded in laravel.log. 
I made a mistake on purpose: "php artisan serverrrrr" and it was recorded in laravel.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution.

I'm using AWS and some logs are in **/var/log/nginx**.

I entered the folder and there's many file as prefix "error_log", one for each application.

So, I did:
`sudo tail -f error_log_myapplication.log` to open console listener.

Then, I wrote `error_log('my message')` in Controller and call my request.

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use PHP's native 'error_log' function.
2. Use 'errorlog' channel driver if you want to log using Larave's 'Log' facade.
   For more details, see this link; https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging

Answer (score 0):

If you were not found any error in laravel.log file.Then you guess you need to check your server's php error.log file. It will definately help you to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can log error or output into `storage/log/laravel.log` using `error_log('do something')`  even you can pass a variable from your controller

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to write logs from my custom TestCase class. A simple print_r() did the trick.